# Make vim splits always positioned in the same place

Tags: split

Lets say there are multiple splits at the following layout. Is it possible to keep the last two placed in their position when the editing area is closed or unloaded from the buffer list, and fill its remaining real estate with void tilde lines.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                      Editing Area                    |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                      |
|        Another Buuffer                               |
|                                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------
|                                                      |
|        Quickfix list                                 |
|                                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the `vim-bbye` plug-in and the associated `:Bd` command.

It unloads the buffer but keep the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Every window must show exactly one buffer at any moment.

If you don't need some buffer anymore then open another one with `:e foobar.txt` or create a new one with `:enew`.

Comment: It would still redraw the windows, empty buffer would be just hidden.